# I am trying to determine the max element of the matrix but keep getting error (For Loop is MUST)

Tags: python, valueerror

```
a = np.random.randint(1,100,(5,5))
max=a[0]
for n in range(1,100):
    if(a[n] > max): 
        max = a[n]
print(max)
```

**when I run it; It gives this error**

```
if(a[n] > max):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**I tried fixing it but it gives another error**

```
a = np.random.randint(1,100,(5,5))
max=a[0]
for n in range(1,100):
    if(a[n].all > max):
        max = a[n]
print(max)
```

**when I run it again this error pops up**

```
if(a[n].all > max):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cant use `numpy.max()` and `numpy.min()`?

Comment: You have a 2-dimensional array but you're only looping on one. You're doing `max = a[0]` but `a[0]` is a whole row in your matrix...

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first error is because `a[n]` is a list (since your matrix is two dimensional).

Your second error is because `a[n].all()` is a function, not an attribute - hence the `()`. Also, it just returns True if all the values in the `n`'th row are non-zero (i.e. truthy) - **not what you want**.

To find the maximum value of the entire Matrix, you'll need to do some nested looping (or flatten the matrix and do the single loop as your have). Try:

```py
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if a[i][j] > max_val:
            max_val = a[i][j]
```

You'll also need to change your initial max value to the first value of the 2D matrix, so `max_val = a[0][0]`.

**However, since you're using `numpy`, just do `np.amax(a)`.**

Full code should be:

```py
a = np.random.randint(1,100,(5,5))

max_val = a[0][0]
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if a[i][j] > max_val: 
            max_val = a[i][j]

print(max_val)
```

Comment: my bad, don't call your variable `max`, that's a Python function. call it something else, such as `max_val`, or `max_`

Comment: @SadStudent everytime you run `a = np.random.randint(1, 100 (5, 5))` it re-randomized `a`, so of course it's a different value

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid for loop as more as possible, let's try the *numpy.ndarray.max()* function:

```
max = a.max()
print(max)
```

Comment: for loop is a must for this question :(